# Adding scrollbars to fancybox on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a popup form that I am presenting with Fancybox 2 using the following code:

```
$(link).fancybox({
    type: 'iFrame',
    autoSize: false,
    autoScale: false,
    width: '1280px',
    height: '1024px',
    iFrame: {
        scrolling: 'auto'
    }
});
```

The form has several dropdown boxes that I am styling using the Chosen jQuery plugin.  Since they are multiple select, they end up resizing the page and pushing the content off the bottom.  I would like, when the content resizes, to have a vertical scrollbar appear on the fancybox.  I've tried setting the iFrame scrolling to auto and also to yes with no result.  I've also added a scrolling attribute outsize the iFrame attribute and that did not help either.  Can someone tell me how to accomplish this?

Comment: The iframe scroll bars should appear automatically if the content is longer than the box (and the box uses the full height of the viewport) http://jsfiddle.net/gy6f11qm/

Comment: The problem is that the content doesn't need scrollbars when it's initially created.  After selecting some options, the content expands vertically and the scrollbars are not added at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that you have misspell option `iFrame`, it should be `iframe`.

Comment: Double checked my code and only misspelled it in question.  I have fallen into that trap before, though.

Comment: Then fancyBox has nothing to do with your page scrolling or not scrolling. It is up to you and your browser, if you can make it work inside simple <iframe> tag, then it will work the same inside fancyBox.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer ultimately didn't have anything to do with Fancybox.  Someone had added an overflow:hidden to the html and body elements in my stylesheet.  I have no idea what the reasoning was behind that, but I will find out.

As an aside, it would be nice if downvoters would leave a comment.  It's a little frustrating to ask a legitimate question and it get downvoted for no apparent reason.  If I need to ask something better, then let me know.  It's certainly the only way I'll learn.